# Quais são diferenças entre um alias de tipo e interface no TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem, interface

O TypeScript nos permite criar *aliases* para tipos. Por exemplo:

```
type State = 'inactive' | 'active' | 'banned';
```

O `type` permite que também sejam criados tipos para objetos, como:

```
type User = {
  username: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Mas um `interface` também permitem a criação de "tipos" para objetos, assim:

```
interface User {
  username: string;
  age: string;
}
```

Então, quais são as diferenças entre usar um `interface` e um `type` *alias*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Interface

A interface não deixa de ser um tipo, mas ela é um contrato apenas, não é um tipo para ser instanciado. Você pode criar um tipo que se conforma com uma interface existente então haverá um tipo novo que em parte é um tipo existente (uma objeto pode ter vários tipos).

Quando você acessa um objeto pela interface só os membros dela podem ser acessados naquele contexto.

Digamos que ela é um tipo incompleto, por isso precisa sempre de um outro pra existir concretamente.

## Alias

Como o próprio nome diz, o alias de tipo apenas cria um apelido para um tipo existente (ainda que anônimo). O alias não gera um tipo, só dá um novo nome, então em várias situações haverá alguma confusão porque o tipo de verdade é o que deu origem ao apelido (poderá perceber em IDEs e mensagens de erro já que o nome apresentado será o do tipo real e não o apelido).

Não gosto da [documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases), na parte que fala das diferenças, porque ela fala que não cria um novo nome, mas claramente está criando um novo nome, o que não cria é um novo tipo, ele usa um existente e chama de outra coisa. E isso está na parte que fala sobre o que é um *type alias*.

Você pode instanciar um tipo através do seu alias, embora o tipo real daquele objeto será o tipo original e não o nome do alias. Qualquer lugar que espera um tipo pode usar um alias que faça sentido ali.

## Diferenças dos exemplos

O primeiro exemplo cria uma união de valores (não de tipos), então o tipo do objeto que será guardado usando esse alias será uma `string`, mas você poderá se referenciar a ele como `State`, e só os três valores constantes ali poderão ser usados. Na verdade eu não sei nem se isso pode ser chamado de *type alias* (já mencionei que a documentação é ruim? Parece algo comum em linguagens de *script*).

Já o nome `User` poderá ser usado para criar objetos que possuem aquela estrutura, mas o tipo em si é apenas estrutural (anônimo).

Ele pode ser usado diretamente como um tipo completo porque ele costuma estar em cima de um tipo completo, mas nem sempre.

O que pode ter gerado como dúvida é que um alias pode ser usado como uma forma de interface, se ele for usado com um tipo para se conformar, como é uma herança normal, então no exemplo mostrado obterá o mesmo resultado, mas nem todos os aliases serão assim. Embora funcione é melhor usar o mecanismo mais correto para conformar com um tipo que é a interface.

Algo como:

```
class UserSpecial implements User {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/TypeXInterface.ts).

certamente exigirá que essa implementação tenha um `username` do tipo `string` e um `age` do tipo `int`. Não importa se está usando a interface ou o alias de tipo, mas recomendo usar a interface, a não ser que tenha um bom motivo para fazer diferente.

TypeScript é um avanço mas ela tem suas esquisitices, assim como JavaScript já tinha. Até por não ser um usuário ativo da linguagem eu não sei se existe algum motivo válido para usar o *type alias* assim, por isso trabalho como não tendo, e se tiver é algo bem pontual.

Comment: Já precisei fazer um código simples que não soube fazer com `interface` (não sei se tem como): `export type Theme = {
  [K in ThemeColorsKeys]: string;
};`

Answer (score 0):

Um `alias` é análogo a um atalho no contexto de um sistema de arquivos. É apenas uma referência para outro tipo. No seu segundo exemplo (`type User == { ...`), você está criando uma interface anônima e atribuindo ela para um alias nomeado `User`